# how put a hyperlink on a new sheet excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, excel-2010, export-to-excel

I have create this code for : when you enter the name and tel of the cliente a new sheet was create with a page type and he create a link between the name page 1 and the sheet. but all the time he don't know the reference.

```
Sub dupliquer2()

Dim numFeuilClient As String
Dim telFeuilClient As String

Worksheets(2).Visible = True
Worksheets(3).Visible = True

numFeuilClient = InputBox("Nom Client")
telFeuilClient = InputBox("Numéro de Téléphone")

    If numFeuilClient = "" Then
        Worksheets(2).Visible = False
        Worksheets(3).Visible = False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
Sheets("FeuilClient").Range("_suprclient").ClearContents
Sheets("FeuilClient").Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

ActiveSheet.Name = numFeuilClient


 Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("FichierClient").Range("C3"), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "ActiveSheet!A1", TextToDisplay:="Voir Client"


ActiveSheet.Range("_nomclient").Value = numFeuilClient
ActiveSheet.Range("_telclient").Value = telFeuilClient

Sheets("FichierClient").Range("A3").Value = numFeuilClient
Sheets("FichierClient").Range("B3").Value = telFeuilClient
   
With Sheets("FichierClient").Range("A3:B3:C3")
.Insert xlShiftDown
End With

Worksheets(2).Visible = False
Worksheets(3).Visible = False


End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The `Hyperlinks` collection property is a member of the `Sheet` object so you need either `Activesheet.Hyperlinks` or better yet a qualified sheet name `Sheets("MySheet").Hyperlinks`

Comment: hello, thank ou for your answers. but it's the problème. The name of the sheet depend of the name imput before. And i don't know how to create this variable. Or how to select the subadress with the variable numFeuilClient. I'm a begginer so maybe it's a stupide question.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```vb
Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("FichierClient").Range("C3"), Address:="", _
         SubAddress:= "'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:="Voir Client"
```

Comment: Ah yes, so it was the sheet name in `SubAddress`.